# Deleting vertex decomposes graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given is a connected graph with undirected edges such that deleting any vertex decomposes the graph into $\le k$ components, for some $k\ge 2$. Is it true that the graph has a spanning tree with degree at most $k$?

The claim is clearly true if the graph itself is a tree. I checked some articles on vertex connectivity but couldn't find anything related to this.

**Edit**: Tony Huynh found a counterexample. What if the graph is required to be such that removing some vertex does not give a connected graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is false.  Take $K_{n, n+2}$.  Removing any vertex gives a connected graph, so in particular the graph satisfies the condition with $k=2$.  However, it does not contain a spanning tree with maximum degree $2$, since $K_{n, n+2}$ does not contain a Hamiltonian path.

Here is a counterexample that works for all $k$.  Let $G_n$ be the graph obtained from the graph consisting of $n$ parallel edges by subdividing each edge once.  This graph is $2$-connected and in particular satisfies the condition for $k=2$. However, every spanning tree of $G_n$ has maximum degree at least $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see a way to modify this to get a graph with vertex connectivity $1$ as well (i.e., removing some vertex does not give a connected graph)?

Comment: @user137930 Add a "tail" of length 2 to the graph? Or add a mirror of the graph and "bridge" them with one vertex?

Comment: @user44191 Fair enough.